# filtering out some weird lines in a test file in python

Tags: python

I have a very big text file in which I want to get ride of some lines. the first line is Identifier which is followed by many lines (numbers in different lines) like this example:

example:

```
fixedStep ch=GL000219.1 start=52818 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fixedStep ch=GL000219.1 start=52959 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
1.000000
fixedStep ch=M start=52959 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
```

this line is identifier: `fixedStep ch=GL000219.1 start=52818 step=1`
I want to filter out all identifier lines containing "`ch=GL000219.1`" and the following lines (the numbers) and keep other identifiers and the corresponding lines (numbers) below them. like this output:

```
fixedStep ch=M start=52959 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
```

do you know how to do that in python?

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file into a `list` and `loop` through the list checking whether the `conditions` are met to write to file or not. For example:

```
with open('test.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as w:
        data = f.read().splitlines()
        for i in xrange(len(data)):
            if data[i].startswith('fixedStep') and 'ch=GL000219.1' not in data[i]:
                w.write(data[i] + '\n')
                for t in xrange(i+1, len(data)):
                    if data[t].startswith('fixedStep') is False:
                        w.write(data[t] + '\n')
                    else:
                        break
```

output:

```
fixedStep ch=M start=52959 step=1
1.000000
1.000000
```

Comment: @ARM just replace print with write, I edited the answer you can check it now.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a big file, it might be more efficient to process it without reading it whole into memory:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    with open('outfile.txt', 'w') as outfile:
        good_data = True
        for line in f:
            if line.startswith('fixedStep'):
                good_data = 'ch=GL000219.1' not in line
            if good_data:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: I want to put it also in a new file

Comment: Corrected according to your wish :-)

Comment: Likely you had a line even before the first identifier line. The latest edit should take care of that.